# Nuevo plugin for Videojs ads are replacing original video source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am currently building a React application (class components) that has a video player. This video player can play live videos and VOD videos. I am currently trying to add advertisements to the player by using the preroll, midroll and postroll that Nuevo offers.

The advertisements on live videos work perfectly fine, the ad can skipped or end and after that, the live video will resume normally. The issue comes when the ads play on VOD videos, the ad starts but when skipped or when it ends, a message will appear over the player saying that there is no compatible media source found and the player just stops, the original video source is not resumed.

I am not sure why could this be happening, since I am not doing any source change manually or anything like that. Here is part of the code:

```js
export class VideoComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      open: true,
      playerInit: false,
      currSource: this.getInitialCurrentSource(),
      srcId: this.props.sourceId,
      posterImage: null,
      nuevoInitialized: false
    }

    this.currentSource = 0
    this.adStartTime = createRef()
    this.adsInit = createRef()
    this.adsPlayedArray = createRef()
    this.clickedAd = createRef()
    this.adsPlayedArray.current = []
    this.clickedAd.current = false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose()
    }    
    videojs.options.liveui = true
    this.player = videojs("player_1", { liveui: true, preferFullWindow: true })

    this.setState({playerInit: true, srcId: this.props.sourceId})

    this.player.nuevo({
      title: "My video",
      url: "some_url",
      embed: "<iframe src= '" + encodeURI(this.props.videoSource) + "' width='560' height='315' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>",
      zoomInfo: true,
      logo: 'logo.png',
      logourl: 'some_url',
      logoposition: 'RT',
      slideType: 'vertical',
      slideHeight: 108,
      zoomWheel: true,
      liveTimeout: 10,
      rateMenu: false,
      shareMenu: false
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.adsArr !== '' && this.props.adsArr.length > 0 && this.adsInit.current === null) {
      const adArray = this.props.adsArr.map(adElement => {
        const videoType = adElement.src.includes('m3u8') ? 'application/x-mpegURL' : 'video/mp4'
        const adObj = {
          src: adElement.src,
          type: videoType,
          href: adElement.href,
          offset: adElement.offset,
          skip: parseInt(adElement.skip),
          id: adElement.id
        }
        this.adsPlayedArray.current.push(false)
        return adObj
      })

      this.player.vroll(adArray)
      this.adsInit.current = true
    } 
  }

  render() {
    //render code
  }
 }
```

Also, three things are worth mentioning:

1. I have already tried putting the code to add the advertisements in the componentDidMount and it didn't work
2. I have tested this with ads that are .mp4 and .m3u8
3. No errors displayed in the browser console

Thank you for reading.